# Fix which partition ubuntu boots from

Tags: boot

This morning I downloaded the "Install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS" to my external SSD drive--it is on partition /dev/sda1.  I later used this install Ubuntu to the same SSD drive--it is on /dev/sda5 (Partition 5).  The partition /dev/sda4 Swap--it is listed as active.  Long story short I installed the external SSD drive as my new internal hard drive.

When I boot up I get the "*Try or Install Ubuntu" option so I'm pretty sure my computer is booting up from the /dev/sda1 partition.  I want to be able to boot up from the Ubuntu operating installed on the /dev/sda5 partition (I know its installed b/c I can see my user name directory there from when I installed it)

So what would I need to do to be able to boot/run the operating system from the /dev/sda5 partition instead of the /dev/sda1 partition?   Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you boot up and get the `*Try or Install Ubuntu` option, I'm pretty sure you didn't remove your installation media.

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu installation partition and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Open gparted and takes a screenshot of the window. Then upload it into your question. You may have to change the boot flag to a different partition: `/dev/sda2`, or`/dev/sda3`, or `/dev/sda5` depending on the type of installation, Legacy, or UEFI.